# Why does the Github Pages not use my CSS archive?

Tags: html, css, github

I'm trying to host my page on *Github Pages* but it is not recognizing my CSS file. I've tried changing the names, rearranging the folders and it still doesn't work. Does anyone know what can I do?

[Here](https://github.com/barbmariana/resilia-project1) is my GitHub project.

I tried change the folder names, and putting the CSS file in the main folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your index.html file is on the same level as your css folder. You'll need to remove `./` from `./css/style.css` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I just checked it out and it looks like the CSS is loading.
[Your github page](https://barbmariana.github.io/resilia-project1/)

If you change your CSS link from

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

I think your css wil work, happy coding!